# iOS bundle identifier on multiple accounts

Tags: provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, apple-developer-account

I am starting a new iOS project for a third party and need to use their specified bundle ID as it also links with a third party API that will likely check the bundleID.
I don’t currently have access to their developer account.
I am worried that if I start the project and use my dev account so I can run it on my device, will this stop them registering the bundleID under their account?

Do unique bundle ID’s only come into affect when adding as an app on AppStore Connect?
Will it be fine whilst using a development build or should I try with a different one?

Answer (score 1):

> will this stop them registering the bundleID under their account?

Not if *you* don’t register it. Just don’t start selling it on your own account.

> Will it be fine whilst using a development build

Yes.

Comment: By selling, you mean uploading to App Store. So adding to xcode and having xcode register it for a signing certificate against my account to develop with and run on my device will be ok?

Comment: Sorry. You edited your answer as I typed the comment ‍♂️

Comment: It seems this is in fact wrong :( Xcode gives the error, The app identifier cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available.

Comment: Well, you must have done something where you exposed the app identifier to the dev center. You asked if it would be okay using a development build, and the answer is yes. But as soon as you do a deployment on your own phone, that changes everything. But it isn't what you asked.

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess that was an important part as I’d be testing the app on a device. So in this case I’m better using a different budleID

Comment: Or they could hand the app over to you. But the usual thing is they just make you part of their team. It seems silly that they don't just do that.